# react native : How to clear the state with navigation 5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I'm trying to clear the state with navigation 5 but it's not working for me.
In my example there are 2 screens: screen A and screen B, when I switch from screen A to B for the first time then I see the information I wanted but when I go back to screen A and then to screen B for the second time then I see the same data I saw before.
I have to reset the state every time I get back to screen B but its not works for me .

**I did this function in both of the screens A and B.**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useFocusEffect` hook. React Navigation provides a hook that runs an effect when the screen comes into focus and cleans it up when it goes out of focus. This is useful for cases such as adding event listeners, for fetching data with an API call when a screen becomes focused, or any other action that needs to happen once the screen comes into view.

This is particularly handy when we are trying to stop something when the page is unfocused, like stopping a video or audio file from playing, or stopping the tracking of a user's location.

```sh
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const unsubscribe = API.subscribe(userId, user => setUser(data));

      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [userId])
  );

  return <ProfileContent user={user} />;
}
```

Reference [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#triggering-an-action-with-the-usefocuseffect-hook)

Comment: i just copy it as is and it will works ? i dont think so ..

Comment: Understand one things, this is just an example. You should adjust example to your own need.

Comment: @jasurkurbanov on telegram